# Update Symantec Definitions in Deep Freeze

Tags: windows-7, symantec, deep-freeze

I've tried every combination of things I can think of to update the Symantec Endpoint Protection definitions in Deep Freeze 8. I have created a Batch file task to run the following command at a specific time:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SepLiveUpdate.exe" -s

No matter what I try, it will not update Symantec when it goes into batch file mode. I have also tried calling a local batch file that runs the command above, but no luck either.

Anyone any ideas?
Thanks!
s

Comment: does it work if you run the command directly?

Comment: Yup! I tried that first just to make sure I wasn't wasting my time :) But it doesn't seem to work when the machine is in batch file mode (where no user is logged in)

Comment: try running the batch file as an administrator? what does the -s do?

Comment: the -s makes it run silently - although that doesn't matter anyway seeing as you can't see anything when it runs in batch mode. I've tried it without the -s too, just to check. As for running as administrator, i've provided the admin details in deep freeze so it should be using them to perform the batch file. there is this old article from 2012 that tells you how to do it with the older version of deep freeze and symantec: http://support.faronics.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/276/8/updating-symantec-enterprise-definitions-during-deep-freeze-maintenance, but nothing recent (thats 2012).

Comment: I'll keep on looking

Answer (score 0):

I used deep freeze for quite some time and if i'm not mistaken you need to disable deep freeze to update it. If having the program run while it's updating is important to you, you might want to look at a few alternatives like shadow defender or drive vaccine.